# Managing shared code in source control

Tags: version-control, git, mercurial, dependency-management

Projects A and B both use library project L:

[image: A and B depend on L]

Judging by what people have written about it on the web, managing this situation appears to be a headache:

http://codingkilledthecat.wordpress.com/2012/04/28/why-your-company-shouldnt-use-git-submodules/
[why you shouldn't use Mercurial subrepos](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11628301/246568)

Are there any solutions out there that avoid difficulties such as:

• Losing work because the VCS did something unexpected
• Hellish subrepo merges
• Screwups caused by the VCS pointing to an unexpected version of the submodule,
   frequently made worse because the user didn't realize that had happened

Comment: Have you had a look at Git Subtree instead of subrepo?

Comment: Noticed its existence is about it.  I just saw that sourcetree supports it, which could be a good sign.

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely no reason to avoid `git submodule`; it works *far* better than most of the alternative "solutions". Just have your build script assert (but not modify; to solve problem 1) that the submodule is present and up-to-date (solves problem 3), and *only* make changes to the submodule as its own repo, *not* as if it's part of the main repo (solves problem 2). I'll repeat that: **only make changes to the submodule as its own repo.**

Additionally, recent versions of git supply `git submodule update --remote` to automatically pull the latest version from the branched you're tracking.

Assuming you are not completely ignoring the most important git command of all time, `git status` (whose output is also included in the editor when you run `git commit`), you won't have any problems.

Of course, if you're using some GUI frontend, it's probably crap, but that's true whether you're using submodules or not.

Comment: Nice post except for the unnecessary GUI remark

Comment: @HaraldScheirich it's far from unnecessary. I have *never* seen any GUI that exposes all the power of the underlying command-line API.